# Compare 2 columns As in 2 separate sheets and if they match add column Bs from each sheet together

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 separate sheets with 2 columns.  I am looking to match Column A from both sheets and add the value of column B to each other and input the sums in a different column.  looking for help.

Sheet 1:

[image: Sheet 1]

Sheet 2:

[image: Sheet 2]

Thank you

Comment: How about combining the two sheets, then sorting on A then adding B if it is the preceding A is the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula, I placed it in column E on Sheet 2.

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE),Sheet1!$B:$B+Sheet2!$B:$B,"")
```

[image: Data on Sheet 1]

[image: Data on Sheet 2]

[image: Result with Formula]